# I need a regular expression to use in php that will add rel='lightbox[nason]' to the a tag where a string /gallery/dsc_ is found

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression to use in php that will add rel='lightbox[nason]' to the a tag where a string /gallery/dsc_ is found.

Example input string:
http://myURL/gallery/dsc_8691-1-bw-3/' title='DSC_8691-1-bw'>

Example output string:
http://myURL/gallery/dsc_8691-1-bw-3/' title='DSC_8691-1-bw' rel='lightbox[nason]'>

Comment: I see that you are new to StackOverflow. Welcome! It is generally recommended that new visitors review our [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page (we're a bit different from most Q/A sites). The best kinds of questions (which typically generate the most answers) usually include some sample code. It helps to see not only what you've tried, but also that you've put some effort into finding a solution on your own.

Comment: You may also find that parsing HTML with regex is generally not recommended. [It is very difficult to do well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/211627), and usually creates a brittle, difficult to maintain solution. You may find there are already [some great solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/292926/211627) for parsing HTML in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Like that

```
$count = null;
$returnValue = preg_replace('~(a.*href=(?:"|\').*/gallery/dsc_.*(?:"|\'))~U', '$1 rel="lightbox[nason]"', '<a href="http://myURL/gallery/dsc_8691-1-bw-3/" title="DSC_8691-1-bw">', -1, $count);
```

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is [very, very difficult](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/211627). I would not recommend this track.

Comment: (Oops... let me try this again) This won't work like you think. Try it against this input: `'<a href="http://myURL/gallery/dsc_8691-1-bw-3/" title="DSC_8691-1-bw"><br /><a href="http://myURL/gallery/dsc_8691-1-bw-3/" title="DSC_8691-1-bw">'`

Comment: I tried this :
`$count = null;
$returnValue = preg_replace('~(a.*href=(?:"|\\\').*/gallery/dsc_.*(?:"|\\\'))~U', '$1 rel="lightbox[nason]"', '<a href="http://myURL/gallery/dsc_8691-1-bw-3/" title="DSC_8691-1-bw"><br /><a href="http://myURL/gallery/dsc_8691-1-bw-3/" title="DSC_8691-1-bw">', -1, $count);`

and obtains :
`<a href="http://myURL/gallery/dsc_8691-1-bw-3/" rel="lightbox[nason]" title="DSC_8691-1-bw"><br /><a href="http://myURL/gallery/dsc_8691-1-bw-3/" rel="lightbox[nason]" title="DSC_8691-1-bw">`

Comment: @user2170212 - Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you.